# force to call ngOnDestroy and ngOnInit

Tags: angular, routes, ionic4, lazy-loading

My components doesnt get killed to be recreated again.

I go to the '/tabs/home/order' and after i change the url to '/tabs/home/wallet' the order page doesnt get destroyed and if i go back to the 'tabs/home/order' the page doenst call ngOnInit
is there anything related to modules or routes structures ?

What triggers the angular lifecycle hooks ?

And how can i force it to kill and recreate when the URL changes ?

[image]

If is there anything related to module structures, the module structure of this project is a garbage, the home module is lazy loaded and loads the Wallet and Order component together and the lifecycle hooks of these components are not calling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The seemingly unexpected behavior you are describing is due to Ionic. More specifically, it is due to [how Ionic deals with the life of a page](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle#how-ionic-handles-the-life-of-a-page).

> When you navigate to a new page, Ionic will keep the old page in the
>   existing DOM, but hide it from your view and transition the new page.

...

> Because of this special handling, the ngOnInit and ngOnDestroy
>   methods might not fire when you would usually think they should.
>
> ngOnInit will only fire each time the page is freshly created, but not
>   when navigated back to the page. For instance, navigating between each
>   page in a tabs interface will only call each page's ngOnInit method
>   once, but not on subsequent visits. ngOnDestroy will only fire when a
>   page "popped".

Without knowing much about your application, I would suggest using the [Ionic Lifecycle events](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle#ionic-page-events) instead of the Angular ones. It sounds like you can probably just replace `ngOnInit` with `ionViewWillEnter` and replace `ngOnDestroy` with `ionViewWillLeave` or `ionViewDidLeave`.

Further down in the documentation is some useful [guidance for each lifecycle method](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle#guidance-for-each-life-cycle-method)